# Clicking/Selecting Check box(s) in CodedUI Testing

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create an Automation CodedUI Testing script (using Visual Studio Premium 2013) where I'm trying to click/Select a **check box(s)**. I have the procedure codes names for few nodes in procedure codes.

How do I make VS to *click those check boxes*?

Thanks :)

Comment: Note: Cross Hair (CodedUI Test Builder) fails to identify/fetch the check box's property and values!

Comment: Does the test-builder find the control if you drag the cross hair near the control and search for it your self (with the arrows)?

Comment: Thanks for your response!

No, the cross hair doesn't highlight the checkbox(s) rather it highlights the treeviewitem(s) right next to it. But once in a blue moon it does highlight the checkbox control which lasts a fraction of a second or less! As a result, the cross hair fails to show the property and values for the checkbox control. 

Whereas record & playback mode somehow managed to click/check the checkbox but didn't populate any result in display window (as per expectation it was suppose to populate result in display window when clicked/checked).

Comment: Could you update your question with the XAML you're testing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's a "winform" application.

Comment: Check weather Cross Hair tool can identify any parent control of checkbox if yes you can use getchildren method to access checkboxes and perform the operation.

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep for your reply! I'll update as soon as I perform the step.

Answer (score 0):

Check over what you get back from calling `GetChildren()` on your identified `WinTreeItem`.
If in the list is a `WinCheckBox` that is most likely what you need to define.

```
var checkBox = new WinCheckBox(yourTreeItem);
checkBox.TryFind();
Mouse.Click(checkBox);
```

Now it is worth mentioning as well `CodedUI` also provides the `WinCheckBoxTreeItem` type of control. Which might bind to your desired check box as well.

```
var treeCheckItem = new WinCheckBoxTreeItem(yourWinTree);
// add search properties like display text
treeCheckItem.TryFind();
treeCheckItem.Checked = true;
```